# render component by id from another page and show only necessary part of that component in react js using functional component

Tags: reactjs

#go to another page using navigate hook , but in another page show only specific row scrolled up,      reactjs coed

Home page : Home.jsx

```
<Card
              bordered={false}
              className="services-card"
              onClick={() =>
                navigate("/offer", { state: { isCardClicked: true } })
              }
            > Mycard
 </card>
```

`Offer.jsx`

```
const scrollRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (location?.state?.isCardClicked) {
      const yOffset = -50;
      const element = document.getElementById("view");
      element?.scrollIntoView();
      window.scrollBy(0, yOffset);
    }
  }, [location]);


 <Row style={customStyles} className="cards_container" id="view"> xyz </Row>

# I want to render this row along with route path with automatical view to specifc height , so that is directly visible without scroll
```